# How to model a Many-to-Many relationship in Google Datastore C# .NET

Tags: c#, google-app-engine, asp.net-core, google-cloud-datastore

I need to model either a one-to-many or a many-to-many relationship in the google-cloud-datastore. There is plenty of documentation for Python RE this concept, however, the documentation for the flexible environment and specifically C# is lacking.

Here is my current code, this results in the keys being stored as json in the datastore.

```
    var keys = request.Subjects.Select(key => new Key().WithElement(Kind.Subject.ToString(), key.ToLower()));

        Key[] keyArray = keys.ToArray();
        Entity requestEntity = new Entity
        {
            Key = this.keyFactory.CreateIncompleteKey(),
            // other properites...
            ["subjects"] = new ArrayValue(keyArray)
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way as in relational database. You just creating additional many to many relational table. https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Another option would be double side pointers. In this case you need to store array of foreign keys in each connected entities. On each entity delete or connection update you need to update this lists from both sides.

I would prefer to go with the first approach, as it much easier, but there are some situations where you might work with the second one.

Comment: Thank for the answer, however, I think you've misunderstood my original question. I do not need to be refreshed on the concept on foreign keys and database design. The Python SKD for the Google Datastore includes a method of defining such a relationship... however, from what I have found; the .NET library does not. Therefore, I am seeking to find the objects to use / the correct method for creating the above.

Comment: @rhys_stubbs, Okay, my fault. But, could you share link where did you find the examples on Python? Because Datastore is NoSQL database and providing ways of relational mapping is client library specific and it is likely that .NET library can just not support them as Python does. I would like to see the Python docs for what you are talking about to make sure we are on the same page.